# Partition column useful or not while taking count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, star-schema-datawarehouse

Which one will be best to use from the perspective of cost, time and processing.here etl_batch_date is the partition column for the table.

1.Query - This query will process 607.7 kb when run
Table size : 9.77 MB

```
SELECT count(*) from demo 
WHERE etlbatchid = '20200003094244327' and etl_batch_date='2020-06-03
```

2. Query - This query will process 427.6 kb when run
   Table size : 9.77MB

   SELECT count(*) from demo WHERE etlbatchid = '20200003094244327'

Also when you write second query then does it read the data from every partition?

You valuable comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Try them both. What do you find?

Comment: When i use partition column than it process more and using second query it process less.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: Always use the partitioned column to filter data.

Play with this query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2020`  
WHERE DATE(datehour) IN ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02')

# 2.2 GB processed
```

For every `datehour` you add to the filter, an extra gigabyte of data will be queried. That's because:

1. Filtering by datehour implies a read of the datehour column. So this makes the query go over more data.
2. But since the datehour column is the partitioned column, then it only scans that day of data.

Now, if I add another filter:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2020`  
WHERE DATE(datehour) IN ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02')
AND wiki='en'
# 686.8 MB processed
```

That processed less data!

That's because `wiki` is the main clustering column.

So try to always use partitions and clusters - even tho for smaller tables the results might look less intuitive.

Comment: This is true felipe we should use partition column to filter the data but when you are not fetching the actual data you are just getting count of table using particular column then do we need to apply this ? And does it look all the partition and then provide a result.

Comment: Yes for the general case. If you want a more specific answer, please ask a question with more specifics. Note that for a table of only 9MB, all these optimizations are almost meaningless.

Comment: Yes but this is jusy dummy data. As I have mentioned in my question while using partition column in query to get count it is taking more processing data while in second query where no partition column in where condition took less processing data

Comment: I agree. But if you were not working with dummy data then my answer would make sense. If you want a better answer with more specifics, ask a question with non-dummy specifics.

Comment: Here my concern is that if i am using partition column and it processing more data and if i am not using partition column and it processing less data than there is not benifit of using partition column in such conditions. Here is the specific question.

Comment: Yes. There's no benefit of using partitions when your table is less than 10MB. Test again with non-dummy data, and then partitions will bring benefits. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes,I will apply this on table contains a good amount of data. I think partition column will definitely help to process less data with some other filter conditions.Thanks. Have a nice day.